# Inserting multiple JPG into SQL using Java

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, blob

I have a folder on my laptop with 7500 JPG images each with a different name (EMPID).
[image]

I have an SQL database with 7500 Corresponding rows. I want to add the images to a column called LNL_BLOB where the Column EMPID has a matching value to the JPG.

Can someone give me some pointers on what this process would be called so i can research it?

Comment: "Inserting binary data" ? Which part of inserting the blobs is stopping you? Reading the files? Matching the IDs? Inserting the blob itself? And also: SQL is not SQL. There are "dialects". Which DB system is in use exactly?

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/blob.html

Comment: Hi Fildor,  I tagged SQL Server which is what i am trying to connect to.  The bit i am having difficulty with is getting and then matching the filename.  From that i can figure out the loop etc i think. Thanks

Comment: You can extract the filename with `Path`. You could then fire a select with according "where" on the EMPID column to find corresponding entries.

Comment: In your snippet, is the first column the EMPID? I see it is not unique ...

Comment: Thats right yes,  I was going to include in my statement where the 3rd Column also =0

Comment: Ah, ok, so it will be unique in that sense. For File operations see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html You may find "listFiles" interesting and "getName".

Comment: Thanks i know what to look at now.  I will update once i have a better idea.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110886/discussion-between-display-name-and-fildor).